# React erroring because of different, mystery object

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm trying to render some JSON and the error I get references some fields that don't exist  in my JSON structure. The fields are getting logged to the console properly.

Which object is this referring to, and how do I fix it?

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_events, _eventsCount, _maxListeners, uri, callback, readable, writable, _qs, _auth, _oauth, _multipart, _redirect, _tunnel, headers, setHeader, hasHeader, getHeader, removeHeader, method, localAddress, pool, dests, __isRequestRequest, _callback, proxy, tunnel, setHost, originalCookieHeader, _disableCookies, _jar, port, host, path, httpModule, agentClass, agent}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Postlist:

```
class PostList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      request('http://194.5.192.153:3044/api/posts/', function (error,response,body) {
        let items = JSON.parse(body).items;
        for(let i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
         console.log(items[i].author,items[i].desc,items[i].updatedAt,items[i].title);
          return (
            <Post author={items[i].author} desc={items[i].desc} image={items[i].image} title={items[i].title} createdAt={items[i].createdAt} updatedAt={items[i].updatedAt} />
          );
        }
      })
    )
  }
}
```

Post:

```
const Post = (props) => {
    return (
      <>
        <img src={props.image} alt="" />
        <h1>{props.title}</h1>
        <h2>by {props.author}</h2>
        <div>Created at {props.createdAt}</div>
        <div>Updated at {props.updatedAt}</div>
        <div>{props.desc}</div>
      </>
    );
}

  export default Post;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are effectively trying to render the return value from `request`, which is certainly not what you want. Since `request` is asynchronous, the general pattern here is to set state in the callback and then map over that state in the render method.

```
class PostList extends React.Component {
  state = { items: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    request(
      "http://194.5.192.153:3044/api/posts/",
      (error, response, body) => {
        const items = JSON.parse(body).items;
        this.setState({ items });
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.items.map((item) => (
      <Post
        key={item.title}
        author={item.author}
        desc={item.desc}
        image={item.image}
        title={item.title}
        createdAt={item.createdAt}
        updatedAt={item.updatedAt}
      />
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: It says `this.setState is not a function`.

Comment: I've seen this.state defined in the constructor sometimes. What effect does that have versus what you've done?

Comment: Sorry, my previous explanation was all wrong. The issue is that `this` is no longer scoped to the component instance when called inside the function declaration. Probably the quickest way to solve it is to use an arrow function instead. See updated code

Comment: That works, thanks!

I just had to add a constructor: 
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { items: [] }
    }

Comment: Ah perfect! Can you upvote/mark this answer as resolved?